# Why Django is not creating Foreign Key constraint on MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I'm not new to Python nor Django, but this is the first time I'm creating a completely new big project from scratch, and also the first time I'm actually creating the models for the whole database and I'm kinda confused here.

Does Django does not really create the ForeignKey constraints on the Database to check if ID exists? It is just a logical python thing that works only when the server is running? Or is it a problem that happens on MySQL?

Just to be clear what I'm talking about, the first thing I noticed because as a Laravel developer on PHP side, I'm used to always check the database diagram that PhpStorm/PyCharm generates by connecting to the database, and on Laravel migrated tables, we can see the arrows pointing to the respective foreign key tables relationships, but on the Django created database there is not a single arrow on the database diagram generated by the JetBrains IDE. So I went testing.

For example, I have the following models:

```py
    class Series(models.Model):

        class Meta:
            app_label = 'core'
            db_table = 'km_series'
            verbose_name_plural = 'series'  # added this to avoid plural being "seriess"

        name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        description = models.TextField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
        cover_img = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
        on_going = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return "{} - ID #{}".format(self.name, self.id)


    class Chapter(models.Model):
    

        class Meta:
            app_label = 'core'
            db_table = 'km_chapter'

        series = models.ForeignKey(Series, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        number = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
        name = models.CharField(max_length=150, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
        date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return "#{} - {}".format(self.number, self.name)
```

I have more than 15 models created already using `models.ForeignKey` along other fields. I just tried creating a new row on MySQL using the `python manage.py shell`.

```py
$ python manage.py shell
>>> from core.models import *
>>> Series
<class 'core.models.base_models.Series'>
>>> one = Series.objects.create(name='Test')
>>> one
<Series: Test - ID #1>
>>> one.id
1
>>> chapter = Chapter.objects.create(number=1)
MySQLdb.OperationalError: (1048, "Column 'series_id' cannot be null")
>>> chapter = Chapter.objects.create(number=1, series_id=2)
>>> chapter
<Chapter: #1 - None>
>>> chapter_1 = Chapter.objects.create(number=1, series=one)
>>> chapter_1
<Chapter: #1 - None>
>>> chapter = Chapter.objects.create(number=1, series_id=25)
```

There is only one ID on database, where the ID is "1"
[image: km_series table]

So how can I be able to add any ID when manually assigning, and not passing the whole instantiated object as foreign_key value?
[image: km_chapter table]

Why Django allows me to set the ID to non-existing IDs on the database? Shouldn't this result in an error? Am I missing something on my models? Why there is no constraint and validations for this kind of thing?

Comment: In series class where is the 'ID' declared? New to Django as well.

Comment: @ImranOmarBukhsh on Django models you don't actually need to specify the ID field for the model, as it is the default UNIQUE identifier for each model, when migration is done it will be created automatically. You just need to specify the "Primary Key"/"Unique Identifier", if you actually need something different from the basic ID PK.

Comment: What does `SHOW CREATE TABLE core_chapter;` in the MySQL shell (`python manage.py dbshell`) tell you? Are there constraints?

Comment: @AKX thanks a lot mate, you got me on the right track. The problem was that for some unknown reason, my database was created using the MySQL Engine MyISAM as default, and this engine does not support FK contraints as I just discovered reading the documentation. I was going to delete the question now but I'm leaving it here so maybe it helps someone with the same problem in the future.

Comment: @Dkage you can write your answer below and mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging a little on why MySQL would have a problem with FK contraints, and after using the `python manage.py dbshell` command to check the table creation as I was recommended doing on a comment, by using `SHOW CREATE TABLE core_chapter;` , I discovered the problem.

For some reason that I don't really know why, my Database was created using MyISAM, which is a MySQL storage engine that does not support FK constraints. I had to change the default to InnoDB, as it works with this types of validations for relationships between tables.

On my `my.cnf` file which holds the confs for MySQL, I enforced InnoDB as default by adding the `default-storage-engine` property

```
[mysqld]
default-storage-engine = InnoDB
```

And on Django settings, I also added the DATABASE "OPTIONS", as stated on the [Django documentation for databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/databases/#creating-your-tables), so my DATABASES value was changed to:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'database_name',
        'USER': 'database_user',
        'PASSWORD': '****',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS': {'init_command': 'SET default_storage_engine=INNODB'},
    }
}
```

After changing all that, dropping all database tables and then calling the `python manage.py migrate` again, the constraints were created as expected, and now my PyCharm generated database diagram shows all the arrows showing the relationships flawlessly.